# datamapper: get object order by relationships fields

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

I use Codeigniter with datamapper orm and have a problem

this are my models:

> mailing -> has many row
>
> row -> has many cell
>
> cell -> has many version
>
> version has one created and one updated field.

I want to get the last 10 mailings order by last version changes created or updated..

I thought to do it like this:

```
$versions = new Version();
```

now get last 10 versions order by created or updated

and distinct by mailing_id and now get all mailings to show...
like this: ?

```
foreach ($version as $v) 
{
$v->mailing->get();
}
```

thx for helping

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can call `->get()` on every related model inside a loop but this would generate a [*n+1 query* scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-issue) and be slow if you are looping over lots of version rows.

You can use the [`include_related`](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/getadvanced.html#include_related) to get full `Mailing` instances loaded with data when you query `Version`s in one step (with a join behind a curtain) like this:

```
$versions = new Version;
$versions->order_by(...)->limit(...); // add your ordering and limiting as before
$versions->include_related('mailing', null, true, true);
// include related mailings, with of their fields and create instances, see
$versions->get();

foreach ($versions as $version) {
    // now the $version->mailing is a Mailing instance loaded with the related data
    print $version->mailing->id
}
```